# Issue with Env. Variable while passing URL to Obj and Process Studio in BluePrism

Tags: blueprism

When using env. variable to pass the URL in Obj Studio and hence to Process Studio in Blue Prism, the process runs as expected but after the first Run the URL variable gets deleted from the Obj Studio and becomes blank. Hence while running second time it throws exception. 
Any one faced this issue or Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Sounds like you're not actually using an Environment Variable. Can you show us a screenshot of the configuration of the data item that's becoming blank?

Answer (score 0):

firstly I would pass the Env. Variable to the process studio.

when you are building out the solution within the object studio create your input variable which will call for the env var from the main process. This way you know that you are always passing in the evn var to the correct page utilising it.